# Enumerate permissions without the possibility to change the request e-mail address

Tags: permissions

We want to give managers the rights to view who is authorized to visit their sites without giving any extra right on top of this. Working in SharePoint 2010.
The permission level "Enumerate permissions" looks exactly what we need. However, during my test, we found out that this permission also gives the possibility to change the "Manage Access Requests" options: they can completely disable or change the e-mail address here. Is there a way to give users right to view permissions, without the possibility to change this?